# AVPlayerLayer: get rect of visible part of played video

Tags: ios, iphone, avfoundation, avplayer

`AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` has method `metadataOutputRectOfInterestForRect` which allows to calculate rectangle of visible (on the layer) part of the camera view *taking video gravity into account*.

How this can be done for `AVPlayerLayer`?

Answer (score 0):

how about duplicating the math of AVPlayer's fitIn?

1. you can get the AVAsset behind it

   1. get the frame size it has.
2. You have the view's size

visibileRect = CGRectDoFitIn(assetFrame viewFrame)

Comment: Yep, I ended up duplicating fitIn math i.e. centering the video vertically while fitting it horizontally (assuming orientation is fixed).